# How do I use a custom WPF/XAML control in another project?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

I was able to create a custom WPF Glass Button extending the Button class, and using a ControlTemplate defined in a Style defined in a resource dictionary.

In the project that houses the control, it works fine and behaves as expected.

When I try to place the control in another project, I get nothing - nothing appears. There's no error, but no control presents itself.

I've tried to construct the control with a UserControl, but it errors on some of the properties in a trigger -

```
<UserControl.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True"> <!--'IsPressed' member is not valid because it does not have a qualifying type name.-->
        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Glow" Value="Hidden"/> <!--The name "Glow" is not recognized."-->
        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="Shine" Value="0.4"/> <!--The name "Shine" is not recognized."-->
        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="#CC000000"/> <!--The name "Border" is not recognized."-->
    </Trigger>
```

This is the XAML in it's entirety -

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPFTools.Controls.GB"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="GlowOn">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Glow">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="GlowOff">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Glow">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Border x:Name="Border"
        BorderBrush="{Binding BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"
        Background="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"
        BorderThickness="4" CornerRadius="4">
    <Grid x:Name="Contents">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border x:Name="Glow" BorderThickness="1" Height="Auto" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" CornerRadius="4" Opacity="0"
                              Background="{Binding GlowColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"/>
        <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" Height="Auto" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto">
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Viewbox>
        <Border x:Name="Shine" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" CornerRadius="4,4,0,0"
                                Background="{Binding ShineColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
<UserControl.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Glow" Value="Hidden"/>
        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="Shine" Value="0.4"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="#CC000000"/>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Trigger.ExitActions>
            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="GlowOff_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource GlowOff}"/>
        </Trigger.ExitActions>
        <Trigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="GlowOn_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource GlowOn}"/>
        </Trigger.EnterActions>
    </Trigger>
</UserControl.Triggers>
```

And this is the code for the class -

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WPFTools.Controls {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for GB.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class GB : Button {

        private static readonly DependencyProperty
    _ShineColor = DependencyProperty.Register( "ShineColor", typeof( Brush ), typeof( GlassButton ), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
        new LinearGradientBrush( ) {
            GradientStops = new GradientStopCollection( ) {
                            new GradientStop(Color.FromArgb(0x99, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF), 0.0D),
                            new GradientStop(Color.FromArgb(0x33, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF), 1.0D) },
            EndPoint = new Point( 0.5D, 1.0D ), StartPoint = new Point( 0.5D, 0.0D )
        } ) ), _GlowColor = DependencyProperty.Register( "GlowColor", typeof( Brush ), typeof( GlassButton ), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
        new RadialGradientBrush( ) {
            GradientStops = new GradientStopCollection( ){
                            new GradientStop( Color.FromArgb( 0xB2, 0x8D, 0xD8, 0xFF ), 0.0D),
                            new GradientStop( Color.FromArgb( 0x00, 0x8D, 0xD8, 0xFF ), 1.0D) },
            RelativeTransform = new TranslateTransform( ) { X = -0.25D, Y = 0.5D },
        } ) );

        public Brush ShineColor {
            get { return GetValue( GB._ShineColor ) as Brush; }
            set { SetValue( GB._ShineColor, value ); }
        }

        public Brush GlowColor {
            get { return GetValue( GB._GlowColor ) as Brush; }
            set { SetValue( GB._GlowColor, value ); }
        }

        public GB( ) {
            InitializeComponent( );
        }
    }
}
```

I am clearly doing something wrong here - I just need to know what it is.

Comment: `I am clearly doing something wrong here - I just need to know what it is` - Basically everything. Start reading [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I understand the new project is WPF too, The style, where did you defined it?, if it was in the other project it is not being read in the new project. You need to copy to the new resource dictionary to the new project and reference it.

Comment: @HighCore
Not quite - Thank you for the link; what I was doing wrong was that I had changed the name of the resource dictionary XAML from Generic to GlassButton, and I had not modified the ThemeInfo in the assembly. Addressing these two points, and storing the control template properly has resolved the issue nicely. I would not have been able to figure this out had you not provided that link though, so, thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

So, as it turns out a link provided gave me the answer to my problem -

First of all : when I created the project that houses my custom WPF controls, I made the mistake of changing the name of the `Generic.xaml` that is created within the Themes folder. That is apparently a no-no.

The second mistake I made was that I had not modified the ThemeInfo in the assembly.cs to indicate that there were resources needed.

Addressing both of these has corrected my problem, and the button is now appearing as it should and I can continue testing with it.